# How to show grecaptcha in a popup on clicking CF7 Submit button?

Tags: wordpress, popup, contact-form-7, grecaptcha

I'm making a new form in Contact Form 7. I need to display grecaptcha in a popup on submit button click. After the captcha success need to submit Contact Form 7.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can create your own functionality with JavaScript.
[skip_mail](https://contactform7.com/additional-settings/) -> take CF7 data by [DOM Event](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/) using wpcf7beforesubmit([added in cf7 4.9](https://contactform7.com/2017/08/18/contact-form-7-49/)) -> then create pop-up with your captcha -> then check it. If captha ok -> sending email by yourself with taken data.